# How to expand object values in powershell array

Tags: azure, powershell

I have written a powershell script:

```
$getAllSubIds = Get-AzSubscription
$test = $getAllSubIds[0]

$sqlMetaData = @()
foreach ($subscription in $getAllSubIds) {
    $info = "" | Select VmName, ResourceGroupName, SubscriptionID, SubscriptionName
    $setSubContext = Set-AzContext -Subscription $subscription
    $getSubVM = Get-AzSqlVM -DefaultProfile $setSubContext

    $info.VmName = $getSubVM.Name
    $info.ResourceGroupName =  $getSubVM.ResourceGroupName
    $info.SubscriptionID = $setSubContext.Subscription.Id
    $info.SubscriptionName = $setSubContext.Subscription.Name

    $sqlMetaData += $info
    }
```

$sqlMetaData looks like this:

[image]

Comment: `{...}` symbolizes that the property is an array. You would need to either loop through each element of that array to expand them or use `Out-String` or use `-join` with a delimiter depending on how you want to see the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[`Format-Table`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-table) `-Wrap` is the key to allowing a single column value to *span multiple lines*.**

For that, however, **the values must be *multi-line strings*, not *arrays***, as in your case, so **you need a [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties) in order to transform arrays to multi-line strings**.

A simplified example:

Default formatting represents arrays enclosed in `{ ... }`, always on a *single* line, with elements that don't fit truncated with `...`:

```sh
PS> [pscustomobject] @{ foo = , "x" * 5; bar = 42 } 

foo           bar
---           ---
{x, x, x, x…}  42
```

Using `Format-Table` with a calculated property that turns the 5-element array into a 5-line *string* via `` join "`n" ``, which is then shown in full, thanks to `-Wrap`:

```sh
PS> [pscustomobject] @{ foo = , "x" * 5; bar = 42 } | 
      Format-Table -Wrap @{ n='foo'; e={ $_.foo -join "`n" } }, bar

foo       bar
---       ---
x          42
x
x
x
x
```

<sup>Note: You must use a calculated property (`@{ ... }`) for *each* property that you want represented this way.</sup>

In order to **show *duplicates* of the *non-array* property values alongside the expanded array elements**, use the following:

```sh
PS> [pscustomobject] @{ foo = , "x" * 5; bar = 42 } | 
      Format-Table -Wrap @{ n='foo'; e={ $_.foo -join "`n" } }, 
                         @{ n='bar'; e={ , $_.bar * $_.foo.Count -join "`n" } }

foo       bar
---       ---
x         42
x         42
x         42
x         42
x         42
```

**Caveats**:

- `Format-*` cmdlets should only ever be used to produce *for-display* output; they output *formatting instructions* rather than the original data.

  - In order to make PowerShell *default* to the custom table formatting above (which then wouldn't interfere with later processing *as data*), you'd have to author [formatting data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Format.ps1xml) and associate it with the .NET type(s) of interest.
- Large arrays among the property values can make the output unreadable; you could implement custom truncation, however (e.g., show at most 5 lines).

Comment: Glad to hear it, @angel101. I've added the command from my previous comment to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do something like this as long as the VmNames and ResourceGroupNames are all strings

```
$sqlMetaData | 
    Select-Object @{name = 'VmNames'; expression = { $_.VmName -join ', ' } },
                  @{name = 'ResourceGroupNames'; expression = { $_.ResourceGroupName -join ', ' } },
                  SubscriptionID,
                  SubscriptionName
```

Or

```
$sqlMetaData | 
    Select-Object @{name = 'VmNames'; expression = { $_.VmName -join "`n" } },
                  @{name = 'ResourceGroupNames'; expression = { $_.ResourceGroupName -join "`n" } },
                  SubscriptionID,
                  SubscriptionName | 
                      Format-Table -Wrap
```

Comment: I agree with this answer, I was thinking about exporting the data instead of displaying in the host. The problem with multi line string is that he wont be able to filter later if exported to csv for example

Comment: how do I repeat the SubscriptionID and SubscriptionName as well. Its ok if its duplicated multilines.